# References for this statement on convex functions?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Here is the statement :

> $\forall n \ge 2$, if $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous convex function whose the non empty set $f^{-1}\{(0) \}$ is compact then $\lim \limits_{\Vert x \Vert \to +\infty } f(x)=+\infty.$

It seems similar to Whitney's statement on the set of zeroes of a continuous function.

So, it would be great if someone had references about this result.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You need the zero set to be non-empty: think of $f(x)=e^{-x_1}$.

Comment: What do you mean by $x \to +\infty$ if $x \in \mathbb R^n$?  Maybe you mean $|x| \to +\infty$?

Comment: @Mindlak Indeed my mistake !

Comment: @RobertIsrael That's it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, translate so $f(0) = 0$.  Take $R$ large enough that $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is contained in  the open ball $B$  of radius $R$ about $0$.  Since $f$ is continuous and the complement of this ball is connected, $f$ is either always positive or always negative outside $B$. By looking at the restriction of $f$ to a line through $0$, we see that it must be positive. Moreover, if $m = \inf_{\|x\| = R} f(x)$, we find that for every
$s$ on the sphere $S = \{x: \|x\| = R\}$ and $t > 1$, since $s = (1-\frac1t) 0 + \frac{1}{t} (ts)$, 
$ f(s) \le \frac{1}{t} f(ts)$, i.e. $f(ts) \ge t f(s)$, and thus taking $t = \|x\|/R$ and $s = R x/\|x\|$, 
$ f(x) \ge m \|x\|/R $ for $\|x\| \ge R$.

Comment: Thank you but, I do not see why if we look at the restriction of $f$ to a line through $0$, $f$ is positive ?

Comment: If $g$ is a convex function on $\mathbb R$, you can't have $g(0)=0$, $g(R) < 0$ and $g(-R) < 0$.